# Find rancher running on Linux host

Tags: linux, rancher

Is there a way to determine if Rancher is running on a host just by looking at the services running on it or installed software? What are some of the things/markers that can let someone find rancher instances programmatically on linux devices.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if there are any containers with the name `rancher` on that host.

```
docker ps -a | grep rancher
```